# Android AsyncTask throwing mysterious RuntimeException

Tags: android

On rare occasion, I'm getting this mysterious RuntimeException in one of my AsyncTasks. I have multiple places where I implement AsyncTasks in my app, but no matter how much I dig into these errors I can't seem to get any info about why this RuntimeException is being thrown or what thread it is happening in. Based upon the "completedAbruptly=true" I'm guessing that there's an uncaught exception in the async task, but I don't even know where to begin to try to figure out where... ideas? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It seems that one of your `doInBackground` methods throws the `RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`completedAbruptly=true` happens when the executed task throws an exception. And the task of an `AsyncTask` is executing the `doInBackground` method.

I suggest you wrap your `doInBackground` code into a `try`/`catch` block and let it print exceptions that occur.

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        // ----------
        // do stuff
        return null;
        // ----------
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.e("AsyncTask", "OMGCrash", t);
        // maybe throw it again
        throw new RuntimeException(t);
    }
}
```

That should show you the reason all this happens.

Comment: Interesting; I had already done a try/catch with the generic catch(Exception e), but it seems that Exception e is not within the set covered by Throwable t. In other words, I had assumed that the two were equivalent for handling generic crash cases.

Comment: `Throwable` covers `Exception` and `Error`. Getting an `Error` is rather rare but still possible.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [source code](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-libcore/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java.htm), `completedAbruptly` is a sign that the thread finished due to user interaction. I would guess that the exception happens when an activity is finished before the async task completes. It should be trivial to discard this possibility: just replace one of your AsyncTasks with an infinite loop and press "back" on the emulator.

Comment: Hmm, very helpful, but I only have one activity in the app... no activities are being completed. Furthermore, I'm not even touching the screen or interacting with the device in any way for a ~30 second window around when the crash happens, so I'm not sure what "user interaction" is triggering this... hmm...